# The meaning of "uniform in x" in differential equations

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I have to find the uniform (in $x$) steady state (in $t$) of 
$$\frac{∂A}{∂t} = 1 + R\frac{A^2}{H} − A +\frac{∂^2A}{∂x^2}$$
$$\frac{∂H}{∂t} = Q(A^2 − H) + P\frac{∂^2H}{∂x^2}$$
with no-flux boundary conditions.
What does the uniform in $x$ part mean?

Comment: Is it correct that it means that we can say that $\frac{\partial^2A}{\partial x^2} = 0$ for all $x$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You haven't given us much context here, but I would interpret it to mean that $A$ and $H$ are simply constants, independent of both $t$ and $x$. (As opposed to the kind of steady state where $A$ and $H$ are independent of $t$ but may depend on $x$.)